# Вебхук Битрикс24 долго отвечает

Tags: php, rest, битрикс24, webhook

Проблема: с сайта отправляется заявка в чат телеграм (через телеграм бот) и сразу в СРМ. Сервер ждёт ответа, телеграм отправляет заявку почти мгновенно, а от СРМ Битрикс24 бывает по 4 минуты нужно ждать ответа. И получается на сайте идёт загрузка несколько минут. Иногда Битрикс отвечает быстро, и загрузка только секунды 2, но не всегда.

Что с этим делать? Есть вариант ответить стороне клиента "OK", даже если СРМ ещё не ответила, надеясь, что лид успешно прийдёт. Но мне этот вариант не нравится, потому что есть вероятность что лид прийдёт только в телеграм, а в СРМ нет. И клиент будет потерян.

То есть проблема в скорости ответа СРМ.

Хостинг Fornex, локация Украина.

Ниже код, как я отправляю данные (типа REST API если я правильно понял). Метод вебхука crm.lead.add

```
// отправляем запрос в Б24 и обрабатываем ответ
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $queryURL,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $result = json_decode($result,1); 
 
    // если произошла какая-то ошибка - выведем её
    if(array_key_exists('error', $result)){
        
        die("Ошибка при сохранении лида: ".$result['error_description']);
        //echo 'false';
        
    }else{
        
        echo 'true';
        
    }
```